# Update a d3.js multiline graph on submit event of a html form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, d3.js

I have a JavaScript file which collects data from an html form after submit button is pressed. I use jQuery to accomplish this.
The data is sent to the server where it is processed and results are sent back in json format.
I use the returned results to draw a simple multi-line graph.

Everything is working as expected until you submit the form again.
The graph gets drawn twice.

Can someone assist me on how I can update the graph with the new data coming in from the server.

Below is the JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle the submit button
    // the id of the form is sma_form
    $('#sma_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        create_post();
    });

    // AJAX for posting
    function create_post() {
        // Notify the user that values are being loaded to the server
        $("#smaButton").button('loading');
        // sanity check
        console.log("function create post has been called");
        // Extract the values from the form
        // Everything is fine here
        var ticker = $('#ticker').val();
        console.log(ticker);
        var start_date = $('#backtest_start_date').val();
        console.log(start_date);
        var end_date = $('#backtest_end_date').val();
        console.log(end_date);
        var sma_cash = $("#sma_cash").find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(sma_cash);
        var sma_comm = $("#sma_comm").find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(sma_comm);
        var sma_size = $("#sma_size").find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(sma_size);
        var sma_days = $("#sma_days").find("option:selected").val();
        console.log(sma_days);

        // Handle the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            // the endpoint
            url : "/equities/create_post/", 
            dataType: "json",
            // http method
            type : "POST", 
            // data sent with the post request
            data : {
                ticker : ticker,
                start_date : start_date,
                end_date : end_date,
                sma_cash : sma_cash,
                sma_commission : sma_comm,
                sma_size : sma_size,
                sma_days : sma_days
            }, 

            // handle a successful response
            success : function(json) {
                 // sanity check
                 console.log("success");
                 console.log(json.starting_portfolio_value);
                 console.log(json.final_portfolio_value);

                 // Store the json containing graph data
                 var sma_graph_data = JSON.parse(json.graph_data);

                 // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
                 var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                     width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
                     height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // parse the date / time
                var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

                // set the ranges
                var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

                // define the 1st line
                var valueline = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

                // define the 2nd line
                var valueline2 = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.sma); });

                // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
                // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
                // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
                // #sma_graph = this is just an id for a div
                var svg = d3.select("#sma_graph").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform",
                     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                // format the data
                sma_graph_data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
                    d.close = +d.close;
                    d.sma = +d.sma;
                });

                // Scale the range of the data for x-axis
                x.domain(d3.extent(sma_graph_data, function(d) { 
                    return d.date; 
                }));

                // Scale the range of the data for y-axis
                y.domain([0, d3.max(sma_graph_data, function(d) {
                    return Math.max(d.close, d.sma); })]);

                // Add the valueline path.
                svg.append("path")
                    .data([sma_graph_data])
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", valueline);

                // Add the valueline2 path.
                svg.append("path")
                    .data([sma_graph_data])
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke", "red")
                    .attr("d", valueline2);

                // Add the X Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

                // Add the Y Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

                // Reset the Loading button
                $("#smaButton").button('reset');
            },

            // handle a non-successful response
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

            }    
        }); // end of ajax call function
    }// end of create_post() function
}); // end of document ready() function
```

Answer (score 0):

When dont you destroy the element (containing graph) first and than make a new one and initiate graph on that. You can remove an element in jquery by:

```
$('#element').remove();
```

and than make a new one and initiate graph on that new element. So it won't be shown twice now.

Comment: I have put the remove statement after this line:   $("#smaButton").button('loading'); The graph does not show. Where should I put the remove statement?

Comment: yeah it would not show since the element is removed.
You wil have to create element again.
you can simply append it in its parent container. For instance, parent container have a class `parent`, so after removing You will write `$('.parent').append('<div id="sma_graph"></div>')`